# Quality of image changes drastically after saving as jpg (choosing max quality) from raw

Tags: photoshop, raw, jpeg, adobe-camera-raw

Why does quality of my image changes drastically after editing it (and saving it as jpg with maximum quality ) in photoshop CC RAW. Everything looks great until I save the image. Comparison of the photo before and after saving/converting as jpg given below.

p.s. I am a little paranoid.[image: After saving]

[image: before saving]

Comment: What particular aspect of "quality" do you feel is changing significantly? Color? Resolution? Noise? Etc.?

Comment: Is your 'paranoid' comment and the blacking out of the subjects' eyes related?

Comment: What resolution are you saving in?

Comment: 1. The noise in the saved image is increased significantly, The sharpening goes away. It feels like after saving the image as jpg it adds loads and loads of grain.

2. yes. 3. the resolution is 6000x4000

Comment: zoom in to 100% and play with the noise reduction options in ACR.

Comment: That is what I do, When I'm done it looks absolutely good and professional even at 100%. But when I export it as jpg(even with quality=12 which is max), some "magic" happens and it gets super noisy and super grainy for God knows what reason. It only happens with D5200 camera raw pictures. Other camera raw works perfect.

Comment: For what it's worth, there are a number of areas where your screenshot of the RAW preview shows worse technical image quality than your exported JPEG. For example, the highlight transitions on your subjects' faces is very harsh, and nicer in the exported version.

Comment: Actually if you open the images into a new tab and look at the details in normal size, it looks horrid. Even the smooth blur due to DoF turns noisy.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of noise from having turned the "clarity" setting up to the max. That's _definitely_ the cause of that particular problem. But I stand by the claim that the screenshot of the RAW preview looks worse in other ways.

Comment: Never mind putting creepy black dots over the subjects' eyes (which I'd say leaves them totally identifiable), I'd be more worried about that ID badge. You can read the organisation name clearly and that barcode is pretty clear too.

Answer (score 2):

It appears most of what you are seeing is due to the use of high *Clarity* and *Vibrance* settings coupled with faster rendering options in the Lr preview window.

Depending on how you've got your viewing quality options selected, Lightroom may or may not be actually recomputing the raw data to produce the preview you see from within Lightroom. If you've got them set to render changes more quickly what you're seeing in Lr is more of an estimate of the effect of those settings rather than the actual effect on the image once it is exported and the settings are actually applied to the raw data.

Since the image in question was shot at ISO 4000 it can be assumed to be relatively noisy. Increasing *Clarity* and *Vibrance* increase microcontrast and thus tend to amplify noise.

Comment: I understand what you are are trying to convey. but how to stop faster rendering options if faster render is causing problems? One more thing is this problem is only with D5200 .NEF raw files. With D7000 raw files, every edited detail looks same before and after saving (even with maximum clarity and vibrance).

Comment: @MuhammadAshar What he's saying is that the *problems are already there*, and you are just not seeing them until you export because of the faster rendering options.

Comment: So this means there can be nothing done about it unless I change the way I edited this picture? Is there no way of avoiding this much grain after exporting?

Comment: You'll have to change the way you edit the photo. If you set the rendering options to "higher quality" instead of "faster" you'll be able to see the effect as you edit instead of waiting until you export.

Comment: But that is what I do.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you have the rendering options set that way? This does seem like the most likely explanation.